# Let $\ \varphi \, : \, V\rightarrow V\ $ be a linear transformation. Prove that $\ Im(\varphi \, \circ \varphi) \subseteq Im \,\varphi\ $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let V be a vector space and $\ \varphi \, : \, V\rightarrow V\ $ be a linear transformation. Prove that:

$$\ Im(\varphi \, \circ \varphi) \subseteq Im \,\varphi\ $$

I am struggling to see what conditions I have to verify, in order to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x\in\text{Im}(\phi\circ\phi)\implies\;\exists\,v\in V\,\,s.t.\,\,\phi\circ\phi(v)=x$$

But $\,\phi\circ\phi(v)=\phi(\phi(v))\,$ , so in fact we got

$$x=\phi(\phi(v))\in\text{Im}(\phi)$$

Comment: Thanks for that, I understand the question and answer now.

Comment: My pleasure and way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Every element of $Im(\phi \circ \phi)$ has the form $(\phi \circ \phi) (x)$ for some $x \in V$. But $\phi : V \rightarrow V$, so $\phi (x) \in V$ as well. So setting $\phi (x) = y$ we have $(\phi \circ \phi )(x) = \phi (y) \in Im(\phi)$.
So every element of $Im(\phi \circ \phi)$ is also in $Im(\phi)$, hence $Im(\phi \circ \phi) \subseteq Im(\phi)$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that 
$$\mathrm{Im}(\varphi)=\{\varphi(x)\quad|\quad x\in V\}$$

Now take $y\in \mathrm{Im}(\varphi\circ \varphi)$ then there's $x\in V$ such that
$$y=\varphi\circ \varphi(x)= \varphi( \underbrace{\varphi(x)}_{z\in V})=\varphi(z)\in \mathrm{Im}(\varphi)$$
so we have
$$\ Im(\varphi \, \circ \varphi) \subseteq Im \,\varphi\ $$

Comment: Nice to see you 'round, as usual!

Answer (score 2):

More generally, for linear maps $U \xrightarrow{\phi} V \xrightarrow{\psi} W$, we have $\mathrm{Im}(\psi \circ \phi) \subseteq \mathrm{Im}(\psi)$.

Proof: $\mathrm{Im}(\psi \circ \phi) = (\psi \circ \phi)(U)=\psi(\phi(U)) \subseteq \psi(V)=\mathrm{Im}(\psi)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in Im(\varphi\circ\varphi)$ and note that $x=\varphi(\varphi(y))$ for some $y\in V$ by the definition of $Im(\varphi\circ\varphi)$. But then $x=\varphi(z)$ where $z=\varphi(y)$ and so $x\in Im(\varphi)$ by the definition of $Im(\varphi)$ as $z\in V$. It follows that $Im(\varphi\circ\varphi)\subseteq Im(\varphi)$.

Comment: Thank you for this, very good answer I was able to follow it and comprehend it, thanks!